# Why does this program enter the if block in Release build but not in Debug build?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I have some code that behaves differently between a Release build and a Debug build.  It behaves correctly in Debug but not in Release.

I have a function that returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<MyCustomClass>`.  One section is this:

```
        var result = new List<MyCustomClass>();
        ...
        var list1 = this.returnEmptyList();
        var list2 = this.returnListWithOneItem();
        if (list1.Count == 0 && list2.Count == 0)
        {
            functionOutVariable = string.Empty;
            return result.AsReadOnly();
        }
```

For the purposes of troubleshooting I've simplified the code and named the variables in a generic fashion, and the methods `returnEmptyList` and `returnListWithOneItem` are shown here:

```
    private List<string> returnEmptyList()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    private List<string> returnListWithOneItem()
    {
        return new List<string> {"something"};
    }
```

Clearly it should never enter the `if` block because `list2.Count` should always be 1, but when I execute this in a Release build, it *does*:

[image]

So there's clearly some optimization going on since you can see that `list1` is inaccessible, and when stepping through it executed line 416 and then jumped immediately to line 421.  I should state that all the assemblies in my solution use .NET Framework 4.6.2, and I'm running Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.5.

When I change the build to Debug and execute this, it executes line 416, 417, and on line 418 it shows `list1.Count` is 0 and `list2.Count` is 1, and it correctly does *not* enter the `if` block.

I'm trying to make a test project to reproduce this but I can't.  I'm looking for any way to get to the bottom of this.  I don't just want a fix that makes it go away - I need to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the compiler.  Can you post the compiled IL in each build?

Comment: Debugging in **Release** mode may be problematic: the current statement pointer may not be accurate and variables may get optimized away if you have **Optimize Code** enabled. Go to Project Properties and check under the **Build** tab. Disable if needed, and you may want to enable it again after you're done.

Comment: And what do you do later in this function, if "if" block is not entered?

Comment: Sometimes.. simply printing a line indicator to console helps to debug in release...

Comment: So you are saying you can't reporoduce this in a stand-alone test project?

Comment: To @PeterB's point, can you verify (eg, add `Console.WriteLine()`) that the `if ()` block is actually entered, and it isn't just the debugger being confusing?

Comment: i cannot reproduce that. i made a little console application and copied your samples. 

            var list1 = returnEmptyList();

            var list2 = returnListWithOneItem();
            if (list1.Count == 0 && list2.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entered");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Not Entered");
i never get "entered". silly question, did you rebuild everything? Maybe some old references which arent correct any more...

Comment: Sometimes, the Debugger in Visual Studio just displays (highlights) the wrong lines. Especially when the source code don't match the PDB. Are you sure they match?

Comment: @Evk - I think you're right.  If I comment out the other parts of the function it no longer appears to go into the `if` block.  I think it's likely the compiler has (probably correctly) found an optimization based on the rest of the code and optimized out the `if` block entirely and the debugger is just confused about which line in the source code corresponds with the actual IL it's executing.  I will investigate and post back what I find.

Comment: Yes that's what I had in mind. Say if you do the same thing after "if" (set variable to string.empty and return list) - it might optimize whole "if" away because it's useless anyway.

Comment: This is pretty normal, still generating reliable debug info when the optimizer moves and deletes code is a hard problem.  Basic reason why a Debug configuration exists in the first place.  There is a debugger setting that was designed to avoid this behavior.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Suppress JIT Optimization" checkbox.  Presumably you have it off.  Turning it on prevents the optimizer from doing its job, but realistically you are no longer really debugging the Release built program.  If Ngen.exe was used then this checkbox has no effect.

Comment: @HansPassant - yes, I understand that.  It was really just a "what the heck..." kind of moment.  There was instrumentation in the Three Mile Island control room which indicated [that a certain valve was closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident#Human_factors:_confusion_over_valve_status), but the indication meant the valve was being told to close, not that it was actually closed.  Here I was looking at a debugger telling me something I knew couldn't be true.  If the debugger would gray out the lines it can't find in the IL, that might have made it more clear.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I'm pretty sure it's a result of a subtle bug in the rest of my function that allowed the compiler to just optimize out the if block and return early.  I can reproduce the behavior of the debugger in this test project, and it totally makes sense in this case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new MyClass();
        test.DoTest(out var result);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<MyCustomClass> DoTest(out string functionOutVariable)
    {
        var result = new List<MyCustomClass>();
        var list1 = this.returnEmptyList();
        var list2 = this.returnListWithOneItem();
        if (list1.Count == 0 && list2.Count == 0)
        {
            functionOutVariable = string.Empty;
            return result.AsReadOnly();
        }
        functionOutVariable = string.Empty;
        return result.AsReadOnly();
    }

    private List<string> returnEmptyList()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    private List<string> returnListWithOneItem()
    {
        return new List<string> { "something" };
    }
}

class MyCustomClass
{

}
```

When I execute in a Release build with the debugger, it appears to enter the `if` block, but in reality it just optimized out the `if` block completely and the debugger confusingly shows it executing the lines inside the `if` block instead of jumping over it:

[image]

**Edit:** I've confirmed there was a bug later in the function that was causing my problem, and the behavior of the debugger when looking at Release build code was just causing me confusion, due to compiler optimizations.

To be clear, my question is incorrect: *the function was actually giving the same result in both Release and Debug builds* but I was mistaken.  That's because I followed this (flawed) sequence:

1. I had a failing test (against a Release build).
2. I ran the test with the debugger (still in Release build) and saw it *apparently* go into the `if` block incorrectly.
3. I then switched the build to Debug and ran the test with the debugger and saw it step over the `if` block.  *I assumed (incorrectly) that was the source of my problem.*

That sent me on the wild goose chase seen above.  Sorry for wasting your time, but I certainly found the exercise informative.  Perhaps someone else will learn from my mistake in the future.  :)